# The sum of in-degrees $\sum_{v\in V} id(v)$ and out-degrees $\sum_{v\in V} od(v)$ are always equal?

Tags: graph-theory

I'm working on Problem #24 of section 11.3 of Ralph P. Grimaldi's Discrete and Combinatorial Mathematics, an Applied Introduction, fifth edition.

Question:

*Let $G=(V,E)$ be a directed graph, where $|V|=n$ and $|E|=e$. What are the values for $\sum_{v\in V} id(v)$ and $\sum_{v\in V} od(v)$?*

$id(v)$ and $od(v)$ are the in-degrees and out-degrees.

In and out degrees are mentioned in passing at the end of section 11.3, so one is left on their own to answer this question.

I tried to deduce the facts necessary about $\sum_{v\in V} id(v)$ and $\sum_{v\in V} od(v)$ and I'de like to know if my logic is correct:

Given a finite number of vertices $n$ for every 'directed' edge you add you are adding $1$ to $\sum_{v\in V} id(v)$ and $\sum_{v\in V} od(v)$ respectively, and they must always be equal?

If so, then $\sum_{v\in V} id(v)=\sum_{v\in V} od(v)=e?$

Comment: Yes, seems correct to me.

Comment: Yup! The Handshaking Lemma, but for directed graphs! Here summing all the degrees (ins and outs) gives you $2e$. I'm sure this has been asked many times. Check out [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1560613/400626).

Comment: thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your idea rigorous, you need to use induction. Let $Q(k)$ be the statement that every directed graph with exactly $k$ edges satisfies the desired claim. Then use induction on $Q$. When doing so, be careful that you do **not** do anything like "If $Q(k)$ is true, then let $G$ be any directed graph with $k$ edges and add an edge..."! Read [this explanation of induction](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/10034/1550) to make sure you do induction correctly.

Comment: I read the link to the explanantion of induction and feel a little confused:/ Uhm how I would go about it, start with a structure with exactly k+1 edges and work my way down, because it might not necessarily be true that building a structure with exactly k edges and adding 1 edges cover all the k+1 cases. Let me know if I'm on the right track, or if that was the distinction you meant?

Comment: @nolemonnomelon: That is exactly right! To prove $Q(k+1)$ from $Q(k)$, you need to start with a directed graph with $k+1$ edges, and work your way down to some graph with $k$ edges, on which you can apply $Q(k)$, and then work back up to see what that implies for your original larger graph.

Comment: I found that truth about induction the hard way once in a logic course! So given the right distinction at first, working from a structure that has exactly k+1 edges, the  logic following the remainder of the proof would be very similar to the "start with a structure of exactly k edges, add one edge" right?

Comment: @nolemonnomelon: Similar? Not at all. It only looks similar in extremely simple cases. Since you mentioned logic, ideally you should learn formal FOL reasoning (using Fitch-style natural deduction), and then you can do induction properly automatically. If you want to learn formal induction, feel free to ask me more [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77161/basic-mathematics). The post I linked you to is more of a temporary fix for students who do not know formal FOL reasoning, but it is not a permanent solution.

Comment: For future reference, we continued [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56352584#56352584). =)